# Last StackLayout Item is missing or cut

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin, stacklayout

I am creating xamarin.forms page with a single `ListView`.
Each list item template consist of one vertical `StackLayout` which contains 3 `StackLayout`s inside. The problem is: **I can see only first two stacklayouts
and the third is hidden or cut or skipped**,i dont know, i cannot see it.

```
  <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView x:Name="RoutesList" ItemsSource="{Binding Routes}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell> 
                        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee" Orientation="Vertical" Padding="5,0,0,5" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                                <Label Text="{Binding StartDate}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="#f94" >
                                <Label Text="{Binding RouteType}" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding CreatorFirstName}" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"></Label>
                                <Label Text="{Binding CreatorLastName}" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="End"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>

                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

**How to set layout properties correctly so all stacklayouts and their items contents will fit**? All the binding properties are regular strings\dates. I know that there is `GridLayout` but i wonder how to do this using `StackLayouts` ?

Comment: try assigning HeightRequests to the layouts

Comment: @Jason it doesnt help...

Comment: You should only make one StackLayout expandable, when using multiple views that are expandable the it usually fails to layout correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `RowHeight` property of the `ListView` to something that will show all items. Alternatively you may set `HasUnevenRows` to true, but it is a significantly slower option.